# Conditional probability distribution question issue

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The probability that Meena is on time to catch
the bus to her office is 0.8. Find the probability
that she is late

(a) exactly twice in a 6-day week, and
(b) at least once in a 6-day week.

I have tried it, Please correct it if i am wrong or tell if there is any other easy way to solve it:

$P(\text{Meena on time}): 0.8$

$P(\text{Meena is late}): 1 - 0.8 = 0.2$

i) probability that she is late exactly twice: $\binom{6}{2} (0.8)^2 (0.2)^4$

ii)  probability that she is late at least once: $\binom{6}{1} (0.8)^5 (0.2)^1 + \binom{6}{2} (0.8)^4 (0.2)^2 + \binom{6}{3} (0.8)^3 (0.2)^3 + \binom{6}{4} (0.8)^2 (0.2)^4 + \binom{6}{5} (0.8)^1 (0.2)^5 + \binom{6}{6} (0.8)^0 (0.2)^6$

$ \Rightarrow 6(0.32768)(0.2) + 15(0.4096)(0.4) + 20(0.512) (0.8) + 15 (0.64) (0.16) + 6 (0.8)(0.32) + (0.000064)$

$ \Rightarrow 3.93 + 2.46 + 8.19 + 1.536 + 0.000064$

$\Rightarrow 16.116064$

Please tell me If I am wrong during this question ?

Thanks. Help is appreciated

Comment: This is incorrect, you mix up your probabilities in the first one, and Im not sure where you went wrong in the second but I got a different asnwer

Comment: Why this was down-voted seems anything but clear.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm assuming because hes already asked this exact question once before

Comment: @btcgrl : It seems the poster improved the question to make it acceptable but posted separately rather than editing the original question. Responding to that with unexplained downvoting rather than by explaining to a newbie what the proper procedures are seems rather like a tantrum.

Comment: @btcgrl my previous account was blocked and i can't comment or get any answer through that. You told me to give it try and then come back and I have done the same.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks a lot. You seem to be very nice and humble person.

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't downvote it, was merely stating the most likely reason

Comment: @btcgrl No issues. You seem to be very active too. Thanks for helping and correcting me out always. Thanks

Comment: @btcgrl posted a new question. Can you help ? link - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562014/proabability-bayes-theorem-cancer-question

Comment: @MichaelHardy posted a new question. Can you help ? link - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562014/proabability-bayes-theorem-cancer-question#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are doing a specific number of trials, and the probability each time is the same, we can use a binomial random variable to solve it.

For $\text{Binomial}(n, p)$, where $n$ is the number of trials and $p$ is the probability of success on any trial. The general formula is

$$P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

So in your example for part a, the probability she is late on any day is always .2, and we want the probability over 6 days. So we can use $\text{Binomial}(6, .2) $and solve for $P(X=2)$.

$$P(X=2) = \binom{6}{2}.2^2(1-.2)^{6-2} =  .246$$

For part B, we use the same Binomial except this time, we want

$$P(X=1) +P(X=2) + \cdots + P(X=6)$$

Since that would give us the odds of her being late at least once. Instead of doing all that tho, we can just find $1 - P(X=0)$, because her being late at least once is going to be the compliment of her never being late.

$$1 - P(X=0) = 1 - \binom{6}{0}.2^0(1-.2)^{6-0} = 1- .262 = .738$$

Comment: your calculation for second part is correct ? I am getting a different answer for this. can you verify this ?

Comment: @himanshuchawla its just $1 - .8^6$ which is $1 - .262 = .738$. Edited answer to make it a little more clear

Comment: @himanshuchawla np, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your way of finding the probability that she is late at least once is correct, but there's a simpler way:
$$
\Pr(\text{late at least once}) = 1 - \Pr(\text{on time every day}) = 1 - \left( 0.8 \right)^6.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for support. I have implemented this.

Comment: I am getting a different answer for this. Can you verify your answer after calculation ?